# Store SSH Key on Heroku to Connect Rails App to Remote Thru SFTP

Tags: ruby, heroku, ssh-keys, net-sftp

This is a long shot, but I'm trying to add an ssh key to a Heroku for its use in connecting to another server through SFTP:

```
Net::SFTP.start(HOST, USER, password: PASSWORD, keys: ['yada.pem']) do |sftp|
  @sftp = sftp
end
```

My original solution was to push a .ssh directory to the repo and store `yada.pem` there. `keys` would include the path to this file.

A safer solution I've been told would be to store the key in an environment variable on Heroku. Problem is, this would store the key as a string, which I  couldn't really pass to SFTP.start.

I could solve the problem in a couple ways:

1. Is there a way to pass the key as a string with Ruby `net/sftp`?
2. Is there a way to add a public key to Heroku so that `net/sftp` would use it when trying to connect to the remote server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass keys as strings in the option hash under the key :key_data (should be an array of strings, each element of which containing a key in PEM format).

```
Net::SFTP.start(HOST, USER, password: PASSWORD, key_data: ['PEM key as string']) do |sftp|
  @sftp = sftp
end
```

See [`Net::SSH#start`](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start) (to which `Net::SFTP#start` defers).

Comment: Thanks, I totally saw `keys` on that same page and overlooked `key_data`.